# Aspirants "to" the job or "for" the job?

Tags: grammar

Which of the two sentences is correct ?

*1. There are huge number of aspirants **to** the job.*

*2. There are huge number of aspirants **for** the job.*

Comment: The problem is with using *aspirants* rather than *to* or *for*. You *aspire* to achieve something, which may apply to a dream job for one individual. Having multiple people aspiring to a run of the mill job, though, is a bit odd.

Comment: Alternatively, you can say,'there are huge number of job aspirants'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't imagine saying either one, but if you're going to, then *aspire* and *aspirant* normally take *to*.

I first misread this as about *applicants*, which would certainly take *for*.

Comment: It depends just what you want it to mean. Probably _applicants for the job_. _Aspirants_ is possible, but it implies that the job is something special, something that would fulfil their dreams; the mundane word _job_ is rather inconsistent in tone. It would work with the more formal word _position_ instead of _job_, especially if the position is something special, such as a presidency or fellowship.